# How to edit the value inside an array in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am a beginner in vb.net programming and facing a problem that is how can I edit values inside an array in vb.net?

Answer (score 0):

You access VB.NET array elements by index, like in the following sample string array;

```
arr(0) = "some value"
arr(1) = "another value"

string _str = arr(1)
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: You are welcome. Please check the answer accepted. Good luck with your project. Best regards,

Comment: Should you have more SO questions, please post them separately. Best regards,